# How to factorize the following expression: $2x^4 + 9x^3+8x^2 +9x+2=0$

Tags: polynomials, roots, factoring

> How to factorize the following expression: $2x^4 + 9x^3+8x^2 +9x+2=0$

I have tried finding a root through putting values, but I can't find any factor.

Please help.

---

*PS: I'm an elementary student, the question standard might not match with that of the community but any help would be sincerely
appreciated.*

Comment: Write it as $(2x^2+ax+b)(x^2+cx+d)$ and compare coefficients. Then $f=(2x^2 + x + 2)(x^2 + 4x + 1)$. No magic involved, only elementary computations - as you've requested (or suggested).

Comment: Oh wow. That's really smart. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**

This is a special polynomial, as the coefficients are symmetric.

Now set

$$t:=x+\frac1x$$ so that $$t^2=x^2+\frac1{x^2}+2.$$

Express the equation in terms of $t$ and $t^2$.

> $$2x^2+9x+8+\frac 9x+\frac2{x^2}=2t^2+9t+4=(2t+1)(t+4)=0.$$ $$2x^2+x+2=0,\\x^2+4x+1=0.$$

Comment: How would it click to set an arbitrary variable to $x + \frac{1}{x}$ ? The method is amazing, but I wouldn't be able to think of this in a thousand years. Is there any general method to factor higher degree expressions?

Comment: There are general methods for degrees up to $4$, and none above. You would not be able to think of these in two thousand years (they actually took centuries to be discovered). This particular case can be solved with quadratic roots only.

Comment: @Phymathechem This is a general method of simplyfying problems with polynomials of even degree with symmetric coefficients, but it doesn't work on other polynomials. End even when it works it only reducess degree by a factor of 2, so if you start from a high-degree polynomials you may still end up with a polynomial equation that you cannot solve.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have information about $4$ degree symmetric polynomials in your textbook.  Since it is in my textbook, I thought of dividing directly each side $x ^ 2.$

Here is an alternative way:

$$2x^4 + 9x^3+8x^2 +9x+2=(x^2+ax+b)(2x^2+cx+d)$$

$$2x^4 + 9x^3+8x^2 +9x+2= 2x^4+x^3(c+2a)+x^2(2b+ac+d)+x(ad+bc)+bd$$

So, you get

$$\begin{cases} c+2a=9 \\ 2b+ac+d=8 \\ad+bc=9 \\ bd=2\end{cases}$$

For the next trick you can take $b=±1, d±2$ or $b±2, d=±1.$

Of course only $1$ pair will work.

Then you will get the quadratic equation respect to $a$ (or $c$).

You don't need to think for 1000 years :)

Comment: Nice one, but wouldn't dividing by $x^2$ lead to loss of roots? As in, I am told to avoid dividing the equation by the variable because it usually leads to loss of roots.

Comment: @Phymathechem: Dividing by $x^2$ will only lead to a loss of a root that equals zero. And you can easily see that $x=0$ is not a root of your polynomial.

Comment: @Phymathechem It leads.  Therefore, it should be noted that $x$ is not a root.

Comment: Right, you saved me a lot of thinking. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another point of view is $$2x^{4}+9x^{3}+8x^{2}+9x+2=\\2x^4+x^3+2x^2+8x^3+4x^2+8x +2x^2+x+2=\\
(2x^4+x^3+2x^2)+(8x^3+4x^2+8x) +(2x^2+x+2)=\\
x^2(2x^2+x+2)+4x(2x^2+x+2)+(2x^2+x+2)=\\
(2x^2+x+2)(x^2+4x+1)$$