Complex variables: polynomial problem, solve: $2z^4 + 3z^3 + 5z^2 + 3z + 2 = 0$
My teacher for extension 2 math gave the class this problem.
Solve: $2z^4 + 3z^3 + 5z^2 + 3z + 2 = 0$
Context: Starting complex numbers.
First, I thought to factor it through traditional polynomial techniques, like remainder theorem, etc. I quickly realised this did not work. Also, I thought to use the different roots: $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$, etc.
I am still unsure; a hint would help.

This is a palindromic polynomial, there are established techniques for them.  It basically amounts to looking at linear combinations of each $(z + 1/z)^n$.  Because your equation is $2z^2 + 3z + 5 + 3z^{-1} + 2z^{-2} = 0$.

See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4045876/42969 for a very similar question.

The easiest way is to write the polynomial as $(rz^2+az+b)(z^2+cz+b)$ and to compare coefficients. This gives a solution $a=1$, $b=2$ and $c=d=1$, with $r=2$. Then we have
$$
f(z)=(2z^2 + z + 2)(z^2 + z + 1).
$$
So it does work. Of course, there are more elegant ways to see this, e.g., in this duplicate:
How to factorize the following expression: $2x^4 + 9x^3+8x^2 +9x+2=0$

How is a=1, I though it would equal 2 in this case. Still a bit lost when you got a=1
, b=2, and c=d=1, with r=2.

Multiply out, then you obtain $z^4r + z^3(a + cr) + z^2(ac + b + dr) + z(ad + bc) + bd$. Compare this with your polynomial. Of course, $r=2$. You have confused $a$ and $r$ here. Since $bd=2$ over the integers, you do not have many possibilities. Try $b=2$ and $d=1$.

Can you walk through some of the steps. I still need some clarification.

You are already done. Your polynomial has $3z^3$, so $3=a+2c$. Continue now with the term $5z^2=(ac+b+dr)z^2=(ac+4)z^2$. It gives $ac=1$. But only $1\cdot 1=1$, or $(-1)(-1)=1$ is possible. Done. We have $r=2$, and $a=c=d=1$, and $b=2$.

$2z^4 + 3z^3 + 5z^2 + 3z + 2 = 0$
I am currently up to here, do I use simultaneous equations?
$$\begin{cases}
c + 2a = 3 \
2b + ac + d = 5 \
ad + bc = 3 \
bd = 2
\end{cases}$$

Yes, this is correct. Now just solve this over the positive integers (which is enough here). So $bd=2$ means either $b=1,d=2$ or $b=2,d=1$. Then $2b+ac+d=5$, and so on, see the comments above.
